# Lista de seleção de produtos

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Eu estou querendo desenvolver um site, onde os clientes vão poder montar o seu livro selecionando.

Capa

Tipo de folha

Tipo de design

Quantidade de paginas

ETC...
Vou deixar um link para entender melhor 
https://www.printi.com.br/configuracao-livro

Comment: Obrigado pela a correção.

Answer (score 1):

Bem Asafe, o que queres pode ser Obtido usando o woocommerce plugin, podes encontrar no [pagina oficial da woocomerce](https://woocommerce.com/) , mas para o efeito desejado terás que usar a api do plugin que se encontrar na sua [documentação](https://docs.woocommerce.com), personalizando-o até onde pretendes chegar, o plugin te dá a possibilidade de personalizar em vários pontos como aumentar campos(os que tem no site "detalhes do livro"), calcular frete, etc). Basta dar uma lida e poderá encontrar como colocar isso tudo no seu site Wordpress

Comment: Pois vou estudar mais sobre woocomerce, A minha ideia é criar uma plataforma onde o escritor possa ele mesmo escolher a personalização que ele quiser colocar no livro e no final o valor, Da mesma forma da gráfica Printi onde você pode selecionar o que quiser para o seu livro. Mais de antemão muito obrigado pela a ajuda. Um grande abraço.

Comment: Tal como disse no post, o que pretendes atingir no WP é possível usando o woocommerce, só terás que ler e investigar mais sobre o mesmo. Para ter o mesmo efeito ou melhor no teu site